# How to wait for Wordpress Core to load when writing OOP?

Tags: oop, core

I want to create a helper redirect function that looks like the following:

```
/**
*   Just an example of using redirect()
*/
public function validate_something() {
    if (1 == 0) {
        $this->redirect('register');
    }
}
```

However, on `public function redirect()`, I would like to use some functions that are only available after WordPress core has loaded, such as `get_site_url()`.

With that in mind, I created a sort of intermediate function, that looks like the following:

```
/**
*   Receives a redirect request and passes it to an add_action
*/
public function redirect($to) {
    $this->to = $to;
    add_action( 'init', [$this, 'redirect_wp'], 10, 1 );
}

/**
*    Processes an redirect request
*/
public function redirect_wp() {
    header('Location: '.get_site_url().'/'.$this->to);
    exit;
}
```

However, `redirect_wp()` is never called. Moreover, I feel like I'm doing something architecturally wrong, but I don't know exactly what.

Please, take into account that these redirect methods are much more complex in live code, passing for example error messages and old inputs through sessions. The code above is just an example of the strucutre.

Comment: Your condition is `1 == 0` which can never be true. There's also code missing, we never see where or when `validate_something` is called from, or what your actual check is. Lots of missing info

Comment: Christ, is jut an example of the architecture

Comment: maybe the redirect method is called after the action `init` is fired. then it's too late to hook something. a solution would be to hook `redirect_wp` before to know if there is a redirection and then in `redirect_wp` you test is there is a redirection to do.

Comment: I ask for these things because they are important. E.g. if that object is created on the `init` hook then your check wouldn't work. Or if the `validate_something` method is called too late, etc etc

Answer (score 0):

The core problem is that you are not writing OOP. OOP is about identifying objects in your system, not actions. If you want to identify actions than you are better to follow functional design paradigms (and with wordpress hook system, functional design make much more sense).

In your case redirect is an action, that probably follows an object state transition, therefor it should not be an external API of the class.

Of course the object in this case can be a "redirect controller", or better a "browser" object but for most people that will be one abstraction level too much.

> Please, take into account that these redirect methods are much more complex in live code, passing for example error messages and old inputs through sessions

So this is a case where you have a complex decision tree, but it doesn't sound like you have any object state transition, therefor it is not actually something that should be part of an object, at least not more than a utility function.

Answer (score -1):

Add actions/filters in constructor method.

```
public function __construct(){
   add_action('init', [ $this, 'real_constructor_goes_here' ]);
}
```

Comment: Note that this makes it difficult to impossible to test the object without it immediatley adding hooks. A `run` `init` or `start` method would be useful for that purpose

Comment: downvoted since this is an OOP question, so answer should be OOP and not just use classes ;) Constructor should set an object to initial good state. If the good state means it should do something on system init, than you need to raise an exception when you are already past init.

Comment: Question isn't about php oop, but having a core code available. Which is in most cases happen to be `init` action hook. No one can stop you from running your object, but if you want to use core code, please set it to happend after 'init'.